# phpmyadmin login fixed to http even though auth_type = cookie

Tags: phpmyadmin

Ive got a fresh install of RHEL6 (tried with CENTOS6 as well) and when I install phpmyadmin (from epel) and `cp config.sample.inc.php config.inc.php`, changing blowfish to something random about 12 chars long and checking `auth_type = cookie`, it only ever pops up an HTTP Basic Auth form and never the html form.

I've tried googling but cant seem to find an answer. Have tried setting `chmod 777` to php session folder too.  I've even tried a reboot :(  Any ideas?

Comment: what do you want to achieve..??

Comment: being able to login with the html form instead of the browser's default login form as with basic auth.

Answer (score 0):

Your config.inc.php should look something like this:

```
    $cfg['blowfish_secret'] = 'xampp'; 
    $i = 0;
    $i++;
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']  = 'cookie';
/*more text below*/
```

For me this gives out the login form

[image]